# Xamarin Studio Community Error: A valid Xcode installation could not be found

Tags: xcode, xamarin-studio

I'm using Xamarin Studio v5.10.3 and Xcode v7.3.1

I get this error on Xamarin Studio

> A valid Xcode installation could not be found. If your copy of Xcode is installed to a non-standard prefix, please specify the location in Xamarin Studio Community's Preferences under 'SDK location'.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

All is explained in the error :

1) You have to have a valid installed copy of Xcode
**OR**
2) You have to updated you Xamarin Studio configuration to specify the path to you Xcode unofficial installation.